# Finding the value of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Does anyone know how to find the exact sum of

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n}
$$

I've only taken second semester calculus and don't see how to go about computing this sum. The only way that I know how to find the sum of an infinite series is if it is a geometric series.

Using WolframAlpha, I found that the sum for this series is $\log(2)$.

Comment: See the hint in this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565945/interval-of-convergence/565975#565975).

Answer (score 3):

The Taylor series of the function $\ln{x}$ centered at $x = 1$ is given by

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n} (x - 1)^n$$

Set $n = 2$ in this equation.

---

To prove this, note that if $f(x) = \ln{x}$, we have

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{1}{x} \\
f''(x) &= -\frac{1}{x^2} \\
f^{(3)}(x) &= \frac{2!}{x^3} \\
f^{(4)}(x) &= -\frac{3!}{x^4} \\
\end{align*}

and so on.